# Line search method of scipy optimize minimize function

Tags: optimization, scipy

I am conducting research on optimization using scipy library, and have a question regarding with default line search method implemented in this library. I would like to write a description of the optimization method including what kind of line search method was applied. I run the optimization code using default options (BFGS) with unconstrained nonlinear objective function. Anyone who knows if scipy minimize function uses wolfe line search as a default? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/adc4f4f7bab120ccfab9383aba272954a0a12fb0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L1027) reveals that they use the [`_line_search_wolfe12`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/adc4f4f7bab120ccfab9383aba272954a0a12fb0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L827) function. So yes, it uses Wolfe line search.